# Update MYSQL timestamp column but not greater than now()

Tags: mysql

I need to update a mysql timestamp column but not greater then today with an update statement.

```
  SELECT invoice, last_tested_date, (last_login_date + INTERVAL + 1100 DAY) as updated_date 
  FROM test.testApp 
  order by updated_date desc;
```

I want to add 1100 days to the last_tested_date. I don't want that timestamp column last_tested_date to be greater than now();

How can I do this with a simple update statement.??

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE testApp
SET last_tested_date = LEAST(DATE_ADD(`last_login_date`, INTERVAL 1100 DAY), NOW());
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdac17/2)